# Phusion Passenger cannot start Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to run basic Rails apps on my server.

I'm running Ubuntu and nginx. Ideally I'd like to be able to still run php apps so nginx+Phusion seems like the way to go.

> A source file that the application requires, is missing.
>   It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
>   A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
>   Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
>
> Error message:
>   no such file to load -- bundler
>
> Exception class:
>   LoadError
>
> 0  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
>   1   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in`require'
>   2   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb  325 in `prepare_app_process'
>   3   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   156 in`initialize_server'
>   4   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb  563 in `report_app_init_status'
>   5   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   154 in`initialize_server'
>   6   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    204 in `start_synchronously'
>   7   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    180 in`start'
>   8   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb   129 in `start'
>   9   /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  253 in`spawn_rack_application'
>   10  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 132 in `lookup_or_add'
>   11  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  246 in`spawn_rack_application'
>   12  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 82  in `synchronize'
>   13  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb 79  in`synchronize'
>   14  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  244 in `spawn_rack_application'
>   15  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  137 in`spawn_application'
>   16  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb  275 in `handle_spawn_application'
>   17  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    357 in`**send**'
>   18  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    357 in `server_main_loop'
>   19  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb    206 in`start_synchronously'
>   20  /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.19/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server   99

Comment: try `gem install bundler` before proceeding

Comment: no luck. I've run that and bundle install

Comment: which ruby: /home/evan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin/ruby

Comment: which bundle: /home/evan/.rvm/bin/bundle

Comment: `rvm gemset list`
Can help you ensure if you are using the right gemset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you installed passenger to your system ruby installation and not for the 1.9.3-p374 version via rvm. Try to follow the below steps:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p374
gem install bundler passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Then use the instructions from the last command and configure your apache with them. Additionally, go to the project directory and do

```
rvm use 1.9.3-p374
bundle install
```

That should do the trick.